# New representation from an old representation of of $S_n$

Tags: representation-theory

I have a representation, $R$, of the symmetric group, $S_n$, on a vector space $\mathbf{C}^{2^n}$.
The action of $\sigma$ on each basis vector of the form $\mathbf{e}_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes \mathbf{e}_n$ is given by:

$$
R(\sigma) \cdot \mathbf{e}_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes \mathbf{e}_n = \mathbf{e}_{\sigma^{-1} (1)} \otimes \cdots \otimes \mathbf{e}_{\sigma^{-1} (n)}.
$$

Here $R(\sigma)$ is the matrix corresponding to the action of $\sigma$. From this representation, I have defined another representation, $R'$, of $S_n$. This time $S_n$ acts on $\mathcal{L} ( \mathbf{C}^{2^n} ) $, the space of linear operators on $\mathbf{C}^{2^n}$, via the rule:

$$
R' ( \sigma ) A = R(\sigma) A R(\sigma)^{-1}.
$$

Suppoe I know the structure of the representation $R$. This can be derived using Schur-Weyl duality.

Is there a systematic way of deriving the structure of the representation $R'$ from the knowledge of that of $R$? Any references?

Comment: $R'\cong R\otimes R^\vee$, so you need to know how representations interact with tensor products.

Comment: Is $R^{\vee}$ here the dual representation? 

I just also realized that $R'$ can be be thought of as a tensor product of representations. Any references on how to understand the decomposition of the tensor product of the representations at hand?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_symmetric_group#Kronecker_coefficients